# SWIFT Message Testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need help, I have been told to do performance testing using Jmeter on IBM MQ for **SWIFT message types, they are the format or schema used to send messages to financial institutions on the SWIFT network**.

Has anyone had done any testing using jmeter, I need help or sample code how we can do testing using Jmeter for SWIFT Message, looks like we need to change the data during run time.
https://www.iso20022.org/15022/uhb/finmt541.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for sending messages to IBMMQ is quite simple:

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants

import javax.jms.Session

def hostName = "your IBMMQ Host"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

def destination = sess.createQueue(queueName)

conn.start()

def producer = sess.createProducer(destination)

def payload = "your message here"
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

producer.send(msg)


producer.close()
```

Check out the following material:

- [Write and run your first IBM MQ JMS application](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-develop-mq-jms/)
- [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

With regards to building the SWIFT message - you have already provided the link showing how the body should look like.

Comment: Thanks, but how to change the body during run time, when I have pass these data as payload , I need to change data as well for example in the 98a is mandatory field where I need to pass today date, what logic should I right in Jmeter so that payload contains new date.

Comment: You could do something like `new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')` where you need to pass today's date, if the format is not the one you're looking for - see [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  documentation for possible values and [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how) for more examples